# What is a prepared statement?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, prepared-statement

I see a bunch of lines in the `.log` files in the postgres `pg_log` directory that say something like:

> ERROR:  prepared statement "pdo_pgsql_stmt_09e097f4" does not exist

What are prepared statements, and what kinds of things can cause these error messages to be displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-prepare.html):

> A prepared statement is a server-side
>   object that can be used to optimize
>   performance. When the PREPARE
>   statement is executed, the specifie
>   statement is parsed, rewritten, and
>   planned. When an EXECUTE command is
>   subsequently issued, the prepared
>   statement need only be executed. Thus,
>   the parsing, rewriting, and planning
>   stages are only performed once,
>   instead of every time the statement is
>   executed.

Searching the net, I found that the "pdo_pgsql_stmt" command is from some sort of PHP-connection to your database. Maybe [this link](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php) can help you find a suiteable mailing-list or issue-tracker that you can send your error-messages to?

---

EDIT: I think I found your bug here:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37870